# How to show all validation errors as a list in my messagebox

Tags: vb.net

I am having a problem with my code. I am trying to show all the validation errors in a message box. Can anyone tell me why only one of my errors is showing up in the box? I tried a couple more solutions and looked around but I need a little help please.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    If Data_Validated_ok() = False Then Exit Sub


End Sub
Private Function Data_Validated_ok() As Boolean

    Dim intErrCount As Integer
    Dim strErrMessage As String = String.Empty
    Dim ctrlError As New Collection

    ' make sure Premium channel is selected

    If Me.lstPremium.SelectedIndex < 0 Then
        intErrCount = intErrCount + 1
        strErrMessage = intErrCount & ". Premium Channels is a required field." _
        & vbCrLf
        ctrlError.Add(lstPremium.SelectedIndex)
    End If
    ' make sure a customer type is selected in the Radioboxes

    If radBusiness.Checked = False And
                radResidential.Checked = False Then
        intErrCount = intErrCount + 1
        strErrMessage = intErrCount & ".Customer Type is a required field." _
         & vbCrLf
        ctrlError.Add(radBusiness.Checked, radResidential.Checked)
    End If

    ' make sure a business customer checks at least one option in the listbox

    If radBusiness.Checked = True And Me.lstConnections.SelectedIndex < 0 Then
        intErrCount = intErrCount + 1
        strErrMessage = intErrCount & ". Business Customers must select 1 or more Connection." _
        & vbCrLf
        ctrlError.Add(lstConnections.SelectedIndex)
    End If

    ' show all errors in a messagebox

    If intErrCount > 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show(strErrMessage, "Validation Rule(s)", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Dim ctrl As Control
        ctrl = ctrlError.Item(1)
        ctrl.Focus()
        Return False
    Else
        Return True
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Because you are not concatenating the messages with &=, you are assigning the variable the next message.

Comment: Thank you OneFineDay this did the trick I had to put the & before the = on the strmessage

Answer (score 0):

How about storing each error in a `List(Of String)`? Your variable `ctrlError` is not storing controls, but integers and booleans - you should have casting errors there.

```
Private Function Data_Validated_ok() As Boolean
  Dim errorMsgs As New List(Of String)
' make sure Premium channel is selected

  If Me.lstPremium.SelectedIndex < 0 Then
     errorMsgs.Add("Premium Channels is a required field.")
  End If
' make sure a customer type is selected in the Radioboxes

  If radBusiness.Checked = False AndAlso
            radResidential.Checked = False Then
    errorMsgs.Add("Customer Type is a required field.")
  End If

' make sure a business customer checks at least one option in the listbox

  If radBusiness.Checked = True And Me.lstConnections.SelectedIndex < 0 Then
    errorMsgs.Add("Business Customers must select 1 or more Connection.")
  End If

' show all errors in a messagebox

  If errorMsgs.Count > 0 Then
    MessageBox.Show(String.Join(Environment.Newline, errorMsgs.ToArray), "Validation Rule(s)", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    Return False
  Else
    Return True
  End If

End Function
```